# How can I register a function to use with pongo templates?

Tags: go, pongo2

I want to be able to register a function in pongo2 to be able to use in the template. I don't want to use it as a filter. I want to call it as a function. How can I go about this? I don't see any method to RegisterFunction like I can RegisterFilter

I have tried to use RegisterFilter but it doesn't fit my exact use-case which is to call a function to get some data and not to filter an input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pongo2 - call golang function from pongo template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546834/pongo2-call-golang-function-from-pongo-template)

Comment: @apxp No that is about registerfilter i am asking about registerfunction

Comment: "it doesn't fit my exact use-case" - So describe your exact use-case or should we guess what it is? Show some code. Your question is not clear for me and for others. You can edit your question to add some more information.

Comment: "it doesn't fit my exact use-case **which is to call a function to get some data and not to filter an input**" I want to call a function not a filter that is my usecase.